# Bamboo server does not starting as a service

Tags: service, bamboo

I'm working on making bamboo service started as a service.

This is the error that i have got:

```
**ERROR** [PluginSchedulerTask-IncompatiblePluginsCheckPluginJob-job] 
[AbstractUpmScheduledJob] Error executing job 
'**IncompatiblePluginsCheckPluginJob**'<br>
com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference$InitializationException: 
com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference$InitializationException: com.atlassian.extras.common.LicenseException: **Failed to verify the license.**
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference.getInterruptibly(LazyReference.java:152)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:115)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.ResettableLazyReference.get(ResettableLazyReference.java:89)
    at com.atlassian.upm.pac.PacClientImpl.isPacReachable(PacClientImpl.java:267)
    at com.atlassian.upm.pac.PacClientImpl.getIncompatiblePlugins(PacClientImpl.java:638)
    at com.atlassian.upm.schedule.IncompatiblePluginsCheckJob$IncompatiblePluginsCheckPluginJob.executeInternal(IncompatiblePluginsCheckJob.java:74)
    at com.atlassian.upm.schedule.IncompatiblePluginsCheckJob$IncompatiblePluginsCheckPluginJob.executeInternal(IncompatiblePluginsCheckJob.java:67)
    at com.atlassian.upm.schedule.AbstractUpmScheduledJob$AbstractPluginJob.execute(AbstractUpmScheduledJob.java:60)
    at com.atlassian.upm.schedule.IncompatiblePluginsCheckJob$IncompatiblePluginsCheckPluginJob.execute(IncompatiblePluginsCheckJob.java:67)
    at com.atlassian.sal.core.scheduling.TimerPluginScheduler$PluginTimerTask.run(TimerPluginScheduler.java:89)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)<br>
**Caused by**: 
com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference$InitializationException: 
com.atlassian.extras.common.LicenseException: **Failed to verify the license.**
```

Comment: Do you have the correct license?

Comment: How can i verify that ? if it's correct or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error looks like your license is not correct or expired.

Go to Administration **Configuration -> System -> License Details and check "Support period lasts until"** date.

Comment: I'm using debian as a OS  , I didn't found the Licence Dettails and check.
The bamboo server is not working Now because of this error.

Comment: @Baini.Marouane Can you use another license key or check with your Atlassian order if the license key is valid and in date?

Comment: Thank you for your response, i solved the pb , from the beginning it's not a license pb it's apache that can reach the 80 port , i change it to 8060 abd it works finnaly, i solve this issue because i look to an other log path it's 
/home/user/Downloads/bamboo/logs

Comment: @Baini.Marouane Great!